# Converting Specified Elements of a NumPy Array by a New Value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to convert the specified elements of the NumPy array `A`: 1, 5, and 8 into 0.

So I did the following:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])

bad_values = (A==1)|(A==5)|(A==8)

A[bad_values] = 0

print A
```

Yes, I got the expected result, i.e., new array.

However, in my real world problem, the given array (A) is very large and is also 2-dimensional, and the number of bad_values to be converted into 0 are also too many. So, I tried the following way of doing that:

```
bads = [1,5,8] # Suppose they are the values to be converted into 0

bad_values = A == x for x in bads  # HERE is the problem I am facing
```

How can I do this?

Then, of course the remaining is the same as before.

```
A[bad_values] = 0

print A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the index of where a bad value occurs in your array `A`, you could use `in1d` to find out which values are in `bads`:

```
>>> np.in1d(A, bads)
array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So you can just write `A[np.in1d(A, bads)] = 0` to set the bad values of `A` to `0`.

**EDIT**: If your array is 2D, one way would be to use the `in1d` method and then reshape:

```
>>> B = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> B
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

>>> np.in1d(B, bads).reshape(3, 3)
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

So you could do the following:

```
>>> B[np.in1d(B, bads).reshape(3, 3)] = 0
>>> B
array([[0, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [6, 7, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I forget to mention that my REAL array A is two dimensional. Is your solution still okay?

Comment: Thank you so much. Accepted. Would up vote if I had >15 points.

Comment: No problem at all! Glad you found the answer helpful.